# Ошибка при сравнении строк String при использовании DecimalFormat в одной из них

Tags: java, строки, junit, сравнение, формат

Выдаёт ошибку при сравнении полученной строки "String b" с аналогичным значением:

```
@Test
public void test(){
    String a = "1 000,00";
    String b = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00").format(1000); //1 000,00
    Assert.assertEquals(a, b); //выдаёт ошибку, что значения отличаются
}
```

Лог ошибки:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :1 000,00
Actual   :1 000,00
```

И также при использовании замены символов результат не меняется:

```
b = b.replaceAll("//s",""); //1 000,00
```

Comment: Используйте `assertTrue(a.equals(b))`

Comment: Таким способом сравнение завершается ошибкой

Comment: там совсем другой результат выдает
`org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :1 000,00
Actual   :1,000.00`

Comment: Не решение проблемы, но поможет приблизится к сути - используйте getBytes и посмотрите в каком байте (символе) конкретно отличаются строки

Comment: JVic, вовсе нет, при данном формате "#,##0.00" строка принимает значение "1 000,00". Тут всё зависит от Locale. При 'ru_RU' результат соответствует тому, что я написал, а вашем варианте 'en_US'. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html

Comment: по-умолчанию в качестве разделителя используется неразрывный пробел. Википедия [утверждает](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C#%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2), что так и надо

Comment: вот, судя по всему, в этом неразрывном пробеле и ошибка. В ответе указал способ, что можно с помощью setGroupingSeparator задать обычный пробел вместо неразрывного в качестве разделителя.

Answer (score 2):

Нашёл вот такой способ:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("ru", "RU");
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(locale);
symbols.setGroupingSeparator(' ');
String b = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00", symbols).format(1000); //1 000,00
```